# How is SNMPv3 with USM auth and privacy configured on net-snmp 5.8 to avoid "security service 3 error parsing ScopedPDU"?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have a working net-snmp v5.7 install running on CentOS7, and I am now trying to do the same on net-snmp v5.8 running on CentOS8.

I have configured /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf as follows:

```
syslocation Somewhere
syscontact postmaster@example.com

dontLogTCPWrappersConnects yes
agentaddress udp:161,udp6:161

includeAllDisks 10%

engineID host.example.com
rouser -s usm user1
rouser -s usm user2
```

Users are created in /var/lib/net-snmp/snmpd.conf as follows and a restart converts these as expected:

```
createUser "user1" "SHA256" "password" "AES256" "password"
createUser "user2" "SHA256" "password" "AES256" "password"
```

On the same machine snmpwalk is configured in /etc/snmp/snmp.conf as follows:

```
defversion  3
defsecurityname  user1
defsecuritylevel  authPriv
defauthtype  SHA256
defauthpassphrase  password
defprivtype  AES256
defprivpassphrase  password
```

Attempts to run snmpwalk (with above parameters added to snmp.conf) fails as follows:

```
[root@host ~]# snmpwalk host.example.com
security service 3 error parsing ScopedPDU
security service 3 error parsing ScopedPDU
security service 3 error parsing ScopedPDU
security service 3 error parsing ScopedPDU
security service 3 error parsing ScopedPDU
security service 3 error parsing ScopedPDU
snmpwalk: Timeout (error parsing PDU)
```

Using SHA and AES instead of SHA256 and AES256 has the same effect.

Can anyone confirm what is wrong with the above?

Comment: I've encountered the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 running 5.8

Comment: Eventually switched to certs instead (SNMP3+DTLS) and fixed bugs that made it not work. Net-snmpd 5.9.1 has fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with version 5.8 and 5.9.1 net-snmp.  My problem was that I explicitly set engineid in the snmpd.conf file incorrectly.  I put quotes around the engine id and it converted this string to a hex number.   The format for a valid engine id in byte 5 should conform to RFC3411.
Eventual format that worked in snmpd.conf was
engineid 8001xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
This line for me, with using the MAC address (byte 5 is 03) has 22 total hex numbers and is 11 bytes long

It would have been nice for the net-snmp snmpd to catch this error, but wireshark caught this error, by reporting "Data not Conforming to RFC3411" for the packet.